I need to select in DCOMCnfg under Location tab following settings: "Run application on this computer" but is greyed out
enter image description here
I need to select in DCOMCnfg under Location tab following settings: "Run application on this computer" but is greyed out.
I'm attaching a picture
For the application to work, I must check the "run the application on this computer" checkbox.
I changed the security settings. restarted the services. edited local policy. I checked the time zone. edited the registry
I even tried to edit the registry

Word must be installed locally obviously. Can you attach a picture of the the "General" tab ("Local Path", etc.)

this screenshot is actually an example. problem with kepware application. in the local path there is empty.

Empty means it's not installed locally, hence the disabled checkbox. You must install Word locally to enable "Run application on this computer"
